# Passing an array to parameterized test in gtest

Tags: c++, qt, googletest, googlemock

A parameterized test in gtest allows you to test your code with different parameters without writing multiple copies of the same test.[seen here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value_parameterized-tests)

I have seen examples of passing values, std::pair, std::tuple etc.

But I'm not sure how to pass an array/initializer_list into the test.

Expected something like this :

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Sample, FooTest,
                         testing::Values({1,23,53},{534,34,456));
```

Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any type you want as the parameter. You provide type of parameters when you inherit your test fixture a from class template `WithParamInterface` (or `TestWithParam`):

```
class FooTest: public TestWithParam<std::array<int, 3>>
//class FooTest: public TestWithParam<std::vector<int>>
//class FooTest: public TestWithParam<std::initializer_list<int>> //I'm not sure if this is a good idea, initializer_list has weird lifetime management
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Sample, FooTest,
                         testing::Values(std::array<int, 3>{1,23,53},
                                         std::array<int, 3>{534,34,456});
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/MsYb54).
You cannot use bare brace-init list and let the compiler deduce type, because `::testing::Values()` accepts template parameters and compiler doesn't know what type should that template argument become.

Let's say we have `class BarTest: public TestWithParam<std::string>`. To `::testing::Values` we can pass either actual std::string objects `::testing::Values(std::string{"asdf"}, "qwer"s)` or objects implicitly convertible to std::string, like string literal: `::testing::Values("zxcv")`. The latter will deduce type as `const char*` and the actual std::string is constructed deeper in GoogleTest code.

Comment: No this ends up in compiler error.
```
error: too many arguments to function ‘testing::internal::ValueArray<T ...> testing::Values(T ...) [with T = {}]’
```

Comment: @PorottayumBeefum Hmm, looks like it's required to name the type explicitly in here, I have no idea why: https://godbolt.org/z/MsYb54. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot manh!! I also tried with the std::tuple/std::pair containing an array and its working fine.